# unordered_map of unique_ptr: can't get value from iterator

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I am trying to get a unique_ptr stored in an unordered_map. I use the following code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

int *function()
{
    std::unordered_map< int, std::unique_ptr<int> > hash;

    auto iterator=hash.find(5);
    return iterator->second().get();
}
```

When I try to compile this (gcc 4.7.2) I get the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int* function()’:
test.cpp:9:29: error: no match for call to ‘(std::unique_ptr<int>) ()’
```

I do not understand what is wrong with this code. It's as if I needed to use another method to extract a reference from the iterator, but I know of no way to do it.

Shachar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`second` is a member variable of `std::pair` but you are trying to call it like a function. Use the following instead.

```
return iterator->second.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
return iterator->second().get();
```

Should be this:

```
return iterator->second.get();
```

`second` is not a function but rather a member variable of the `std::pair` contained in the map. The code you have now tries to invoke the `()` operator on the member variable. But since your `std::unique_ptr` (which is stored in `second`) doesn't define such an operator, the compiler fails to find it.